# Islands in pacific ocean

Tags: ocean

Recently, I had a question in an exam about the approximate number of islands in the Pacific Ocean. The options were Two thousand, ten thousand, twenty thousand and thirty thousand. The answer given by the exam board was 30,000. Is this a reliable number or is there a chance that it might be 20,000 or greater than 30,000. Where can I get a somewhat scientific source to verify this ???

Comment: Could be well above 30. It all depends on resolution of the source and definition of the island. Due to tide, some rock outcrops can be connected or otherwise to bigger piece of land. I'd say it is misleading question, unless other info provided

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about geography trivia, not GIS.

Comment: Based on 1:50 000 maps, there are roughly 9300 islands in the sea around New Zealand, assuming half of them belongs to Pacific, I think 30 000 in entire ocean is massive underestimation

Comment: It very much depends on your definition of *Island* and *Pacific Ocean*. Oceans, like deserts, don't have hard boundaries (except for coast) so where you draw the line is somewhat arbitrary, especially around Indonesia and New Guinea. Islands can be semi-submerged, dry at high tide or dry except when it rains; the first two categories *could* be considered islands because it would be disastrous to take a boat over them but I wouldn't consider building a house on them (without tons of waterproofing).. I would argue with the board if you chose 20k and get the mark changed.

Comment: Yes..I searched for some official figures from NOOA, UGS etc but there wasn't any conclusive data to an approximative figure. I think I can put forward an argument before the board that even the question setter might be unable to answer this dispute with solid reliable sources.

Comment: If you were trying to make this calculation using GIS software and got stuck, then describing your precise workflow and where you got stuck would be a focused question.